# Not able to execute Python Script from Java

Tags: java, python-3.x, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a python script from Java using the below code

```
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("api.py").getFile());
        String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
        logger.info("Test1Application - "+fileName);

        File file2 = new File(classLoader.getResource("init.py").getFile());
        String initFileName = file2.getAbsolutePath();
        logger.info("Test1Application - "+initFileName);

        String[] cmd = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "./"+initFileName
        };
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Below are the two python scripts and the shell script (1st api.py):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print("inside python hello")
    return "Python Api is running..."

app.run()
```

2nd Script(init.py):

```
import subprocess
import os
from datetime import datetime
import logging

# Create and configure logger
logging.basicConfig(filename="pythonExecution.log",
                format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                filemode='w')

# Creating an object
logger = logging.getLogger()

# Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


logger.info("Inside init.....")
logger.info(datetime.now())
os.chmod("perm.sh", 0o775)
subprocess.call('./perm.sh')
#subprocess.call('./run_cmd.sh')
logger.info("End of init script")
```

Perm.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "perm start"
chmod 777 *.*
nohup python3 api.py
echo "perm end"
```

Whenever I invoke the first script(api.py) from Java it works completely fine and api is exposed at localhost. But if i use the second script from the same program, it is not getting executed, even the logs file is not created.

I am not sure, what am I missing here or doing wrong in the second scenario, any help would be appreciated?

Note: The code may need some formatting before running in local, since I needed to adjust the tabs to show in code blocks here.

Comment: are you sure you need to run **/bin/bash -c 'script.py'**? why not **python3 script.py** ?

Comment: The cmd works for only first script even if I use it like this `String cmd = "python3 "+initFileName;`
Not able to run second script with this format as well.